# Prove or disprove $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} S(m) \le S(n)$ given that $S(x) = \sup_{k \ge 1} k^{-1} \sum_{i = 1}^k \mathbb{P}(|X_k|>x)$

Tags: probability-theory, inequality

Let $(X_i)_{i\ge 1}$ be a sequence of arbitrary random variable, define $S(x) = \sup_{k \ge 1} k^{-1} \sum_{i = 1}^k \mathbb{P}(|X_k|>x)$.

I want to prove or disprove that $\sum_{m=1}^{n-1} S(m) \le S(n)$, I'm trying to prove a more general statement and I ended up with the sum expression but only have useful information about $S(n)$, if anyone could give a hint or a bit of guidance that would be very helpful.

Comment: Take $X_k=X_1$ for all $k$.

Comment: @geetha290krm got it, thanks for the remark.

Comment: You have a typo in the definition. Clearly, for $ x < y $, $ P ( |X_k| > x ) \geq P ( |X_k| > y) $ and hence $ a_k (x) = k^{-1} \sum_{ i=1}^k P(|X_i| > x )  \geq k^{-1} \sum_{ i=1}^k P(|X_i| > y ) = a_k (y) $. Thus, $ S(x) \geq S(y) $. So, $S$ is a decreasing function and hence you can never expect the result you are looking for.